# Is there a word to describe or to refer to a child who talks sweetly?

Tags: word-request

Nobody can deny how sweet and cute some young children talk; they make you laugh by the way they put words together and it's mainly because of the thought behind it or minor grammatical mistakes. When you're delighted by a child making some funny statements, what words would you use to describe or to refer to them?

> A: Yes. Mosquito want to eat me and I chase him and I tell don't come here.
>
> B: Aren't you a little [the word].

I'm open to adjectives too and it doesn't need to be the words to address a child himself/herself.

Comment: An adjective that can be applied to the child or to the talk? Or to the child when talking so? A _______ child, meaning "a little child speaking as little children do"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo As a noun, I'm looking for a word like **sweet-talker** but we know what sweer-talker means and it doesn't work here. As an adjective something like **eloquent** but again eloquent doesn't work here since although it means gorgeously and perfectly said but it implies having a way with words which abviously cannot be used to describe a child.

Comment: Nouns don't "describe".  Adjectives describe. The idiomatic way to ask for a noun is "What is a word *for* one who does such-and-such..."

Comment: We don't have such a noun, to my knowledge.  **Prattler** might do.

Comment: Again,we have to define “grammatical mistake.” Kids actually say things, for example, *ranned*, because they are applying the pattern they have observed about forming the simple past tense.

Comment: As such, the text you provide is arguably not authentic child speech.

Comment: @Clare 13  well yea you're right. That's a good thing though that it wasn't the intended point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rather common phrase here in the U.S.:

> Kids say the darnedest things

which became somewhat popular with the rise of the [television show with the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kids_Say_the_Darndest_Things). A UK version of the show was named “Kids Say the Funniest Things”, but I don’t know if that expression made it into the vernacular over in the UK as it did here in the US.

As another option, I suppose you could simply say, “You’re so cute!” (The word *cute* can be applied to many contexts; one of them is the kinds of things a young child says, particularly when that child makes an adult laugh.)

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely describe this child to a friend as **adorable**. Then, because that's a very general word (it can describe many different behaviours or even appearance), I'd add something like "S/he says the funniest / randomest / sweetest / cutest / darnedest things" and quote the line.

To the child him/herself I wouldn't give that reply, to be honest. Children know when they're being talked down to! I would probably answer the child's intent, not my impression:

> That was clever of you! / That was thoughtful of you! / What a funny thing to do!

Answer (score 0):

A word that is often using to describe a child's manner of speech:

a **prattling** child

a **prattler**

When used of children it is understood to refer to a child's simple manner of speech as they learn the local idiom.  It can also mean that they speak quite a lot.

Comment: Its rather perjoritive to call a child a prattler. Suggests that they speak a lot of nonsense and are annoying rather than sweet.

Comment: It needn't be pejorative, @James K. Such terms often double as terms of endearment. https://books.google.com/books?id=hboHAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&dq=%22prattler%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGuMvfm7_WAhVGtBQKHdHBD004UBDoAQhDMAU#v=onepage&q=%22prattler%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=HcgOBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT289&dq=%22prattler%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGuMvfm7_WAhVGtBQKHdHBD004UBDoAQhJMAY#v=onepage&q=%22prattler%22&f=false  or https://books.google.com/books?id=hdgAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%22little+prattler%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN0sLznL_WAhVO6GMKHdJ3AjYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22little%20prattler%22&f=false